# Prevent Chrome-Headless from enforncing ssl

Tags: docker, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser

### Setup

I'm running chrome-headless as a container in my docker-compose project. My main app (the one I'd like to test) is named 'app' inside the compose file.

To connect from the chrome-headless container to my app, I'm using the dockers internal containerlinking: http://app:3000

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - 3000:3000

  chrome:
    image: alpeware/chrome-headless-trunk
```

### Problem

While this should be easy going, there is one detail, that makes things complicated: chrome-headless is enforcing ssl on ".app" domains. Since I'm connecting to 'http://app:3000' this rule applies.

When connecting I get this error:

> ```
> net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR at http://app:3000
> ```

### Question

Is there any way to setup chrome-headless to stop enforcing ssl on certain domains?
**Changing the name from 'app' to something else in the docker-compose.yml** actually works, but this seems like a rather ugly workaround.

Thank you

Comment: A workaround is in the question not highlighted enough: **Changing the name from 'app' to something else in the docker-compose.yml actually works**

Comment: Just want to say thank you for even posing this issue! Couldn't for the life of me figure out why I was getting ssl errors when I wasn't using https. I'm just going with renaming the service in lieu of an actual solution.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I can confirm that c**hanging service name form app to app_anything solved the issue** for me as well.

Wanted to post it as an answer there since I've overlooked the solution stated in the question first time when I've opened it ;)